# Open data version of the Foreign Assistance Program Inventory?

Tags: usa, government, state, iati, usaidopen

http://www.usaid.gov/sites/default/files/documents/1868/ForeignAssistanceProgramInventory2013.pdf

You wouldn’t know where I can find an open data version of the pdf (above)? With descriptions of “infrastructure” for example (under economic development).

This is the taxonomy used by USG to classify all USG foreign assistance but I cannot find an open data list of this classification structure.

Comment: Are you looking for regulatory descriptions: what may or may not be funded under a program? Or how money is granted in these programs (which is well answered by @albert)

Comment: By "open data version", I guess you are not talking about the license, but about the data format? What data formats would you deem acceptable?

Comment: I mean a machine readable version - an API or at the very least an excel spreadsheet  - that I can pull into applications. This is the core classification used by all US G to classify all foreign assistance programs - but there does not seem to be any machine readable versions available.

Comment: To answer Joe - This list is applied to every single USG program on the Foreign Assistance website and is the standard classification system for all USG foreign assistance programs. Some definitions of what the USG considers "economic growth/infrastructure" would be useful (like, does it include telecoms? Roads? schools? - or would those go elsewhere?" This list is equivalent to the OECD DAC sector listings (under IATI) - having this published in machine readable formats would go a long way to making it easier to tag projects and data with correct classifications.

Comment: So I am thinking about making creating one for myself and making it available. Would others find this useful?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have requested that a machine-readable (CSV) version of the Standardized Program Structure and Definitions be [posted to this website](http://www.state.gov/f/c24132.htm).  Will circle back when we have confirmation of posting.

Comment: Thank you, Brandon!!  I am happy to host the framework in an open data format on one of my sites if I can get the spreadsheet. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

foreign assistance has it as a spreadsheet you can download, then convert to an open data format:
http://www.foreignassistance.gov/web/Agency_USAID.aspx?budTab=tab_Bud_Impl

Comment: The foreign assistance website has transaction level data associated with the framework. It does NOT have the framework itself (with classification codes  - listed here http://www.state.gov/documents/organization/141836.pdf) in open data formats.

Comment: so essentially, you just want that pdf in a csv?